# File on Python (os.startfile) can't be opend

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file in which search results (paths) are saved.
I only want the very first result to be opend.
I did this with:

```
        with open('search_results.txt','r') as f:
            newest_file = str(f.readline().splitlines())
        print(newest_file)
         os.startfile(newest_file)
```

The print result is: O:/111/222/test_99.zip'
But the error is:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] system cannot find the file specified: O:/111/222/test_99.zip'
An addition: O: Is a drive on the network

I tried also to replace the slashes

newest_file = newest_file.replace('/','\\')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to your problem, you were using `splitlines` which its boundaries were messing up your file path, thus, your script raised the `FileNotFoundError` exception. Using regular split could achieve what you wanted.

```py
import os
with open('search_results.txt','r') as f:
        newest_file = f.read().split("\n")[0] # Reading the file, spliting it by new lines, and getting the first result
        os.startfile(newest_file)
```